# Promises inside of setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got this *routine* function that runs every 60000ms on a *setInterval* function. Inside of this *routine* function, I loop over all the usernames on a parsed JSON(db) and check whether or not they're available via a promise (checkUsername), which is a network request.

However, It's pretty clear to me that this is a terrible approach because the promises **may take more than 60 seconds to complete**, and I've been getting ETIMEDOUT errors all over the place. But I just don't understand promises and asynchrony enough to think of a solution.

What would be a better approach to this?
Would async/await fit here?

```
function routine() { 
  db.users.forEach(userObj => {
   userObj.username.forEach(username => {
    checkUsername(username).then(hasUser => {
    if(!hasUser) {
      bot.sendMessage(userObj.chatId, `‼️ Username @${username} is now AVAILABLE ‼️`);
      removeName(username, userObj.chatId);

    }

    }).catch(err => { 
      console.log(err);

    })

    })
});
}
setInterval(routine, 120000);
```

Comment: How about cancelling the setInterval method while your promise is running, and re-enabling the setInterval after your promise is done. So the 60s timer only starts again after your promise is done.

Comment: This should probably be a job for web sockets. Anytime a change is made or someone deletes their account you could fire a socket event to each connection. On the ui, you would listen for those events and act accordingly. Its a much better approach than constantly making requests to api.

Comment: I'd say either stop the timer as @Rash has suggested or have a flag that you can set & check on each run e.g. `if (!running) { // do stuff }`

Comment: I must mention that checkUsername only scrapes someone else's html page using Cheerio. How would I stop the setInterval to wait for the promise?

Comment: Don't use a setInterval. Simple!

Comment: What about setting the timer to run 60s (or 30s or whatever) after the promise resolves? Would you be interested in a solution implementing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a code snippet that you can run that makes use of `Promise.all` as well as async/await ES7 to make your code a bit easier to handle and understand. I'm also hitting a real API endpoint I found online just for the sake of a complete example.

I've also added a way to stop the timeout for good if you ever want that option.

```js
// How often the timeout will run.
// Since the timeout is dependent on when all the requests finish, the timeout will run this many ms after all the requests finish.
var interval = 5000;

// This is what your db seems to resemble.
var db = {
  users: [{
      username: ['1']
    },
    {
      username: ['2']
    },
    {
      username: ['3']
    },
    {
      username: ['4']
    },
  ]
};

// This will hold the timeout function so you can cancel it at a later time.
var timeoutFn;

// Returns returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises it contains have resolved/rejected. It rejects with the first promise that rejects.
function routine() {
  console.log("-- Running routine function --");

  // Return an array of promises. Please see my comments at the bottom of this whole answer which questions db architecture with username being an array.
  // I'm also using map instead of forEach because map automatically returns and array.
  let promiseArray = db.users.map(userObj => {
    return Promise.all(userObj.username.map(username => {
      // This processUsername() function should do all the work related to the username. It helps to keep the routine function as clean as possible since there's already a lot happening in here.
      return processUsername(username);
    }));
  });

  // Returns an array of array of promises. This means that every single promise within each array (see above) has to resolve before the `then` runs. If any reject, `catch` will run instead.
  return Promise.all(promiseArray).then(() => {
    runRoutineAgain();
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('err:', err)
  });
}

// This will create a timeout and run routine after interval.
function runRoutineAgain() {
  timeoutFn = setTimeout(routine, interval);
}


// This async function returns a promise
async function processUsername(username) {
  // Make API call to get data
  console.log('Processing username for', username);

  // I'm using this free API endpoint online just for the sake of making a complete example. Obviously your API will be returning very different data.
  return await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${username}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json);
      // This is where you can do your processing.
      // if(!hasUser) {
      //    bot.sendMessage(userObj.chatId, `‼️ Username @${username} is now AVAILABLE ‼️`);
      //    removeName(username, userObj.chatId);
      //  }
    });
}


function stopTimeout() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutFn);
}

routine();
```

Basically, I'm using `Promise.all` to capture and wait on the result of individual promises which is very useful since you have many users you need to get data for.

Feel free to open up Web Console to better see the output data.

I'm also using `async`/`await` ES7 syntax just to demonstrate other (easier, some might say) ways to write Promises. I understand Promises can be daunting so here are some links that really hit the nail on the head when trying to learn them.

1. https://javascript.info/promise-basics - This covers Promises
2. https://javascript.info/async-await - This covers async/await

---

*Also is there a reason why you are looping over each username for a user in your original code?*

```
db.users.forEach(userObj => {
   userObj.username.forEach(username => {…
```

If there’s only 1 username for a userObj, that second loop adds unnecessary complexity. But if your db has multiple usernames for a single userObj, then that’s completely fine!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer made me understand promises A LOT better. I also agree with keeping the username processing to the `processUsername` function, however, I'm using this function on other parts of the code and I wanted to keep it as abstract as possible. Each `userObj` contains an array of usernames to be checked, along with its ID.

Comment: @BrunoGarcia - Great, I'm glad it helps! Also, I'm not sure which library you are using for HTTP requests but if `ETIMEDOUT` is an issue for you, you can always use a library like Axios (https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance) and set the timeout to a really large value (or 0 if you never want it to timeout). Not the best practice but if your server is just backlogged with requests, this might help.

Answer (score 1):

```
var interval = 60000;

function routine() { 
  return Promise.all(db.users.map(userObj => {
    return Promise.all(userObj.username.map(username => {
      return checkUsername(username).then(hasUser => {
        if(!hasUser){
          return removeName(username, userObj.chatId).then(function(){
            return bot.sendMessage(userObj.chatId, `‼️ Username @${username} is now AVAILABLE ‼️`)
          })
        }
    }))
  })).then(function(){
    setTimeout(routine, interval);
  }, function(error){
    console.error(error);
    setTimeout(routine, interval);
  })
}

routine();
```

This will run every 60 seconds plus the time it takes to resolve all the requests. If it fails, it will run again in 60 seconds. You could be running into timeout issues if you have too many users. Also, if "removeName" fails, "bot.sendMessage" won't run.

You can end promises many different ways. It depends on what you need to do with the promise.

```
.then(function(){
  //do stuff
  setTimeout(routine, interval);
}, function(error){
  console.error(error);
  setTimeout(routine, interval);
})
```

or

```
.then(function(){
  //do stuff
  setTimeout(routine, interval);
}).catch(function(error){
  console.error(error);
  setTimeout(routine, interval);
})
```

or

```
.catch(function(error){
  console.error(error);
}).finally(function(){
  setTimeout(routine, interval);
})
```

or

```
.finally(function(){
  setTimeout(routine, interval);
})
```

Comment: Why not just use [finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally)?

Comment: You don't catch the error and/or you might want to chain another promise. The setTimeout has to be in both. You could do .catch().finally(), but you don't gain anything. If you don't want to catch an error there, just use finally or .then(f).

Comment: Not sure I understand - you want to run `setTimeout` regardless if there's been an error or not, `finally` would be called in either case.

Comment: If there wasn't anything left to do. I am assuming there might be more. You can do it numerous ways. It depends on what is next. You can do catch().finally() and remove .then(), if that is all there is. If you don't want to catch the error and let it bubble up the promise chain, you can just do finally().

Answer (score -1):

One way is to clear the interval as soon as you start handling the interval-function. Then when your interval-function is done, you can start the interval again. This way your interval is not ticking while your interval-function is being executed. Take a look at below code.

```
let interval = setInterval(routine, 1000)

function routine() {
    let sequence = Promise.resolve()
    sequence
        .then(function () {
            clearInterval(interval)
            return Promise.resolve()
        })

        // ... chain rest of your promise here.
        .then(function (value) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log('I take long time.');
                    resolve()
                }, 5000)
            })
        })

        .then(function () { // in last promise, start the timer again.
            interval = setInterval(routine, 1000)
        })
}
```

Here you interval-function is supposed to run every 1s, but the promise itself takes 5s. So the first thing the method does is stop the timer, then do its job, and finally re-enable the timer.

With timeout,

```
let timeout = setTimeout(routine, 1000)

function routine() {
    let sequence = Promise.resolve()
    sequence
        .then(function () {
            return Promise.resolve()
        })

        // ... chain rest of your promise here.
        .then(function (value) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log('I take long time.');
                    resolve()
                }, 5000)
            })
        })

        .then(function () { // in last promise, start the timer again.
            timeout = setTimeout(routine, 1000)
        })
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `setTimeout` be better suited to this pattern?

Comment: Actually yeah, that would be much clean. Updated the answer.